# setContentView not executed after onRestoreInstanceState

Tags: android

I have the following problem:

After `onRestoreInstanceState` is called, I notice that while `setContentView` is supposed to be called, I keep getting all sorts of exceptions that imply that `setContentView` isn't executed - missing `findViewById`, `getWindow().setFeatureInt()` throwing exception because content view isn't called, black screen instead of the actual screen I am expecting, etc.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: can you show the code of  onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstancestate?

Comment: There is no code, the super is called.
Should I override and do something? I don't have any information I need saved...

Answer (score 0):

You should call setContentView() in OnCreate() of your activity.

Comment: I do, and I do call onCreate, and I do go over setContentView, and I still get the above problems.

Comment: What do you mean by "I do call onCreate"? You should'n call OnCreate by yourself.

Comment: I meant I call it in onCreate.
It works fine regularly, the problem only occurs when returning from onRestore